# Can't figure out why Heap Sort isn't working with a max heap

Tags: c, algorithm, heap, heapsort

I've been scratching my head for the past couple of hours because I can't get my heapSort algorithm to work. My build Max-Heap and max-heapify outputs the correct code, and then I follow the HeapSort algorithm in Cormen's Intro to Algorithms, where you start from

> for(i = A.length and go down to 2)
>
> > ```
> >    then exchange A[1] with A[i]
> >      decrease heap size 
> >      call Max-Heapify(A,1)
> > ```

I start with the array elements[3,4,1,2,7] and build the max heap to be [7, 4, 1, 2, 3], but when I do the sort I get: [1,1,1,2,3].

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct heap {
int size;
int *heaparr;
};

int *heap, size; //*heap makes a pointer to the struct

static void build_max_heap(struct heap *p)
{
int arr[5] = {0};
arr[0] = 3;
arr[1] = 4; 
arr[2] = 1; 
arr[3] = 2; 
arr[4] = 7; 


int count = 0; 
p->heaparr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    p->heaparr[i] = arr[i]; 
    //printf("number of each element: %d ", arr[i]); 
    count++; //count is equal to 10 elements
}
p->size = count-1;  //size of heap is 9
printf("size is : %d", p->size); 


 for (int b = floor(p->size/2-1); b >= 0; b--)
{

    max_heapify(p->heaparr, b, p->size);
    printf("pass");
} 
//printf("%d", p->size/2); //prints 10; 

}

void max_heapify(int *data, int loc, int count) {

int left, right, largest, temp;
left = 2*(loc)+1;  //2 (i which is 0) + 1

printf("your location: %d, your count: %d \n", loc, count);



right = left + 1;  //right child
largest = loc;
printf("parent is: %d, left is: %d, right is: %d \n", data[loc], 
data[left], data[right]);

// if given array of 10 so count = 10, left is 2*5 since we get floor 
of 
(p->size/2). 
if (left <= count && data[left] > data[largest]) { //count is how many 
elements in heap
    largest = left; //update largest for location
    printf("here left child %d  is greater than parent %d \n", 
data[left], data[loc]);
} 
if (right <= count && data[right] > data[largest]) {
    printf("here right child (%d) is greater than parent (%d): \n", 
data[right], data[largest]);
    largest = right; //update largest for recursion

} 

if(largest != loc) {  //original location
    temp = data[loc];  // holds the value of the original location
    data[loc] = data[largest]; //array location now equals 
data[largest]
    data[largest] = temp; //data[largest] (left or right child) = value 
of original location
    max_heapify(data, largest, count); //perculate through. 
}
}
void heap_display(struct heap *h) {
int i;
int count = h->size+ 1; 
for(i=0; i<h->size+1; ++i) {
    printf("|%d|", h->heaparr[i]);
}
    printf("\n");
    printf("intial display is done");
   for (int b = h->size ; b >= 1; b--)
{

    h->heaparr[0]= h->heaparr[b]; 
    h->size--; 
    max_heapify(h->heaparr, 0, h->size);
}
    printf("\n"); 
    h->size = 5; 


for(i=0; i<h->size; ++i) {
    printf("|%d|", h->heaparr[i]);
}

//printf("\n"); */ 
}
void heap_sort(struct heap *p)
{
build_max_heap(&p);
//printf("size: %d ", p->size);
/* for (int i = p->size + 1; i >= 2; i--)
{
    printf("fault");
    p->heaparr[0] = p->heaparr[i]; 
    count--; 
    max_heapify(p->heaparr, 0, count);
} */ 
heap_display(&p); 
}

void main()
 {
int count, i, no;  
struct heap h; 
heap_sort(&h); 

//int arr[10] = {4, 1,3, 2, 16, 9, 10, 14, 8, 7}; 
//heap_sort(&h, arr);

 //heap_display(&h); 

//build_max_heap(arr); 


}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and format your code. Hint: the editor doesn't like tabs; replace them with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with this loop in your `display_heap` function:

```
for (int b = h->size ; b >= 1; b--)
{
    h->heaparr[0]= h->heaparr[b]; 
    h->size--; 
    max_heapify(h->heaparr, 0, h->size);
}
```

What you want is this:

```
while size > 1
    swap the root item (0) with the last item in the heap
    max_heapify(0)
    decrease size
```

It looks like you're missing the swap step. Instead, you're just replacing the root item.

The fix is easy enough:

```
for (int b = h->size ; b >= 1; b--)
{
    int temp = h->heaparr[0];
    h->heaparr[0]= h->heaparr[b]; 
    h->heaparr[b]= temp;
    h->size--; 
    max_heapify(h->heaparr, 0, h->size);
}
```